# fetch GET request with params return 404 in Nextjs 13.4

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Hi there am struggling am trying to send my fetch with params as `id` with request to my api to use it inside my query and by the way my `id` is a string
and am using `Link` with dynamic route folder [...id]
some code to make it clear..

The Link Element

```
<Link href={`/books/${id}`}">Book Number {id}</Link>
```

Client code in my page

```
'use client'
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";


const page = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  const id: string = params.id;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/books/${id}`, method: "GET")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        ....
      });
  }, []);
```

API Route

```
export async function GET(request: NextRequest, { params }: { params: { id: string }) {

  const getAuthorId = params.id
  
//Prisma
  const rents = await db.rent.findMany({
    where: {
      authorId: getAuthorId as string,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(rents);
}
```

Then finally Through error request 404

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/books/55 404 (Not Found)
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

Comment: Are you using the App router or pages? Please provide file path as well.

Comment: Am using App router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh i understand what you are trying to achieve but you are going about it the wrong way.

When you called `/api/books/${id}` and you got this error `GET http://localhost:3000/api/books/55 404 (Not Found)` Its means you have no API route specific to that route.
Meaning if your ```id = 55```` you need to have a route page with its folder hierarchy as app -> api -> books -> 55 -> route.ts. Do you understand.

If you need to have dynamism in your route, you should be using `URLSearchParams`

**Possible Fix**
Do this in your useEffect Client code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/books?id=${id}`, method: "GET")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        ....
      });
```

-Here you are passing the id to the route but as a search Params

Now In your API you can get the id with

```
export async function GET(request: NextRequest, { params }: { params: { id: string }) {
  const getAuthorId = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('id')
  
//Prisma
  const rents = await db.rent.findMany({
    where: {
      authorId: getAuthorId as string,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(rents);
}
```

**NOTE: That your API route folder structure needs to be `app -> api -> books -> route.ts` **

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Hashira for your help as i understand from your advice and make it do the trick as i want i tried the searchparams alreday and it works but am already have a dynamic route page ```app -> books -> [id] -> route.ts``` so if i changed the api folder to make it dynamic too like ```app -> api -> books -> [id] -> route.ts``` gonna work with params!!!

Comment: Thanks man it works after i changed the api route to a dynamic api..